# server give me error about displaying custom listview

Tags: android

I am trying to get ticket response and display it in a custom listview. The problem is that if ticket is present and get such response from server it will display the list perfectly but when there is no ticket present and server response is `Status:failed Msg:No ticket available`.

Below is my code:

```
 class viewticket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogedIn.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)  {
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", u_id));
       // JSONObject jsonArray = jpar.makeHttpRequest(URLMyTicket, "POST", param);

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URLMyTicket, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null)

        {
            try {

                contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                 a=contacts.length();
                Log.v(TAG,""+a);
                if(a > 0 )
                {


                id = new String[contacts.length()];

                 prob = new String[contacts.length()];
                desc = new String[contacts.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String aa = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String bb = c.getString(TAG_PROB);
                    String cc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);

                    Log.v(TAG, "TAG_ID" + aa);
                    Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + bb);
                    Log.v(TAG, "TAGDESC" + cc);
                    id[i] = aa;
                    prob[i] = bb;
                    desc[i] = cc;
                    Log.v(TAG, "aaaaa" + id[i]);
                    Log.v(TAG, "bbbbb" + prob[i]);
                    Log.v(TAG, "ccc" + desc[i]);
                }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
              System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii" );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        Log.v(TAG,"length of aaaaa"+a);
        if(id.length > 0 )//i will get error if ticket is not present Attempt to get length of null array
        {
            Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn.this,id,prob,desc);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(UserLogedIn.this, "No Ticket Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pdialog.hide();
        pdialog.dismiss();



    }

   }
```

if ticket is not present i get following error

> Process: com.example.surun.suruninfocore, PID: 22673
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>               at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.UserLogedIn$viewticket.onPostExecute(UserLogedIn.java:791)
>               at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.UserLogedIn$viewticket.onPostExecute(UserLogedIn.java:720)

See line no 791:

```
if (id.length > 0)
```

and line no 720:

```
class viewticket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your if condition to id!=null && id.length > 0
protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        Log.v(TAG,"length of aaaaa"+a);
        if(id!=null && id.length > 0 )//i will get error if ticket is not present Attempt to get length of null array
        {
            Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn.this,id,prob,desc);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(UserLogedIn.this, "No Ticket Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pdialog.hide();
        pdialog.dismiss();



    }
```

Comment: i used if(id != null && id.length > 0 ) condition but all time it shows no ticket present message even if ticket is present

Comment: it's not possible check id length is greater than 0

Comment: This solution is correct, just null check your array before attempting to get the size

Comment: sir the problem is that when i login first time it will correctely get user id but when i send it through intend on next page it will  display null.if i restart app then it is correctely get userid. app is fine